# How to get this X11 code to work?

Tags: haskell, x11

I was trying to follow the [tutorial on X11](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/X_window_programming_in_Haskell) haskell library, but got a problem - 
the created window is positioned in lower left corner of a screen, instead of top left corner, and the drawing (in method `drawInWin`) doesn't seem to do anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/runghc -Wall

module Main where
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import System.Exit (exitWith, ExitCode(..))
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
 dpy <- openDisplay ""
 let dflt = defaultScreen dpy
     border = blackPixel dpy dflt
     background = whitePixel dpy dflt
 rootw <- rootWindow dpy dflt
 win <- createSimpleWindow dpy rootw 0 0 100 100 1 border background
 setTextProperty dpy win "Hello World" wM_NAME
 mapWindow dpy win
 drawInWin dpy win
 sync dpy False
 threadDelay (10 * 1000000)
 exitWith ExitSuccess

drawInWin :: Display -> Window -> IO ()
drawInWin dpy win = do
 bgcolor <- initColor dpy "green"
 fgcolor <- initColor dpy "blue"
 gc <- createGC dpy win
 setForeground dpy gc bgcolor
 fillRectangle dpy win gc 0 0 100 100
 setForeground dpy gc fgcolor
 fillRectangle dpy win gc 2 2 96 96
 freeGC dpy gc

initColor :: Display -> String -> IO Pixel
initColor dpy color = do
 let colormap = defaultColormap dpy (defaultScreen dpy)
 (apros,real) <- allocNamedColor dpy colormap color
 return $ color_pixel apros
```

Basically, I need to create a simple window with a canvas, on which I will draw some lines.

What am I doing wrong in that snippet?

Versions:

```
X11 - 1.5.0.1
GHC - 6.12.1
OS - Linux Mint 10
Xorg - 1:7.5
```

Comment: It works for me... what version of the X11 library, what version of GHC, what version of your operating system, etc.?

Comment: @DanielWagner - added them to the question.

Comment: @DanielWagner - what puzzles me, is that X11 is a simple binding to native libraries, and as far as I know, X in my system is behavioring normally - thus native libraries should be fine.

Comment: This works for me but I see why it could not work for you. The positioning of the window is not guaranteed, your window manager could override it. As for content of the window, it's hard to tell. This simple program does not redraw its window, and the window manager could be playing tricks that invalidate the canvass. Try a more complete program, one with the event loop that does redraw. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @n.m. - As for drawing, you seem to be right - seems that first few draws are ignored, and having the proper draw loop fixes it. But about positioning of the window - how can window manager override it? I'm not running XMonad or something, I use plain Gnome 2.

Comment: @n.m. - As for position, adding an explicit moveWindow instruction after mapping the window seems to fix it. Can there be some sort of timing issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of bugs related to 64-bit-correctness in the 1.5 release of the X11 bindings. These have been fixed in the 1.6 release, so upgrading should resolve these issues.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.6.0.2, still get the same behavior :(